# Refactoring code to be optimized with the "new" operator

Tags: javascript, oop, new-operator

I'm Studying Kyle Simpson's YDKJS: this and the object prototype, and I'm trying to figure for myself if using `Object.create()` is really more efficient in behavior delegation in linked objects than the operator `this` I have copied Kyle's example code (in the code snippet), and I am asking you to help me to refactor it to use the `new` keyword (or using ES6 `class`) if it's possible. It's just hard for me to take things for granted :)

```js
var Task = {
  setID: function(ID) {this.id = ID;},
  outputID(){console.log(this.id);}
};

var XYZ = Object.create(Task);
XYZ.prepareTask = function(ID, Label){
  this.setID(ID);
  this.label = Label; 
};
XYZ.outputTaskDetails = function(){
  this.outputID();
  console.log(this.label)
}

var myTask = Object.create(XYZ);
myTask.prepareTask("myID","Some Task");
myTask.outputTaskDetails()
console.log(myTask)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing or refactoring service as outlined in the [help]. For working code you might try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but I suspect they would tell you the same thing there

Comment: Hey @charlietfl I'm sorry if I was misunderstood. my question isn't for an assignment or for code writing. I ask it out of personal curiosity to understand how Javascript works and why one approach applies better than the other.

Comment: Just like anything in life .. there are often numerous ways to arrive at same result. With coding , often it boils down to author preference. Read the docs on Object.create() and do a web search for any tutorials that use it to see if that helps you. Other than that this whole question is too broad